# unable to proceed installing ecobertura Eclilpse plugin

Tags: ecobertura

I am using Eclipse-lunar and tried to install ecobertura through http://ecobertura.johoop.de/update

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:

> (profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=).

No repository found containing:

> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity.core,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.core,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.23.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench,3.23.0.v20170503-0014
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.tasks.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-2108
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui,3.23.0.v20170414-0629 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.debug.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ant,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.core,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-1844 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.resources.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.bugs,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.core,3.23.1.v20170623-0008
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.ui,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui,3.23.1.v20170623-0008 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui,3.23.0.v20170411-2108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.google.guava,21.0.0.v20170206-1425 No repository found
>   containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common,6.1.0.v20161115-1612 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.core,6.1.0.v20161115-1612 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.queryparser,6.1.0.v20161115-1612 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature,3.23.1.v20170623-0008
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons,3.23.0.v20170503-0014
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories,1.15.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature,3.23.0.v20170414-0629
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery,3.23.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature,3.23.0.v20170411-2108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature,3.23.0.v20170411-2108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor,3.23.0.v20170411-1844
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ide,3.23.1.v20170623-0008
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature,3.23.0.v20170411-2108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature,3.23.1.v20170623-0008

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are using ecobertura vs. using regular cobertura/(other code coverage tool)?

In my experience I have found that running code coverage is much more stable and efficient running via command line.

In my experience with eclipse, I find it much more enjoyable keeping the ide as lightweight as possible and running tests/coverage with your command line.

See below for links to mvn cobertura and gradle jacoco(alternative to cobertura)

http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html